# Cómo crear una base de datos usando SMO y C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un programa hecho con WPF y C#, este será instalado en muchas computadoras.

El programa requiere de una conexión a una base de datos local (SQL Server Express) porque trabaja en escenarios offline. Existe un servidor central que recolecta los datos de todos los equipos mediante sincronización con Sync Framework.

Todo funciona muy bien, la sincronización se realiza de forma correcta y sin complicaciones.

El problema surge al instalar el programa en un nuevo equipo; el requerimiento es que en el equipo exista una instancia de SQL Server Express llamada VYSICO, así, cuando el programa corre por primera vez, se debe crear la base de datos usando los comandos de SMO. La base de datos se llama Vysico.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
ServerConnection srvConn = new ServerConnection();
srvConn.ServerInstance = ".\\" + instanceName;
srvConn.LoginSecure = false;  
srvConn.Login = sqlServerLogin; // El login es con sa
srvConn.Password = password;

Server server = new Server(srvConn);

Database db = new Database(server, "Vysico"); // Aquí arroja el error
db.Create();
```

Cuando se crea la instancia de Database, me da el siguiente error:

> setparent failed for database Vysico

Y los InnerExceptions me arrojan los siguiente

> Method Not Found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetDatabaseConnection(Sys‌​tem.String)'.

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Les agradezco de antemano su ayuda y tiempo.

Comment: estas seguro cuando defines

srvConn.ServerInstance = ".\\" +instanceName;

la instancia que especificas es la correcta? puedes validarlo si te conectas con el management studio

Comment: Eso está validado, si utilizo un simple SqlConnection, funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

Si te conectas con "sa" podrias usar directo un SqlConnection y ejecutar el [CREATE DATABASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)

No necesitas de `SMO` para crear la db, en el conection string define la db `master`

```
CREATE DATABASE Vysico;
```

asi de simple

Comment: Lo había intentado de esa forma pero también me arrojaban errores de este tipo:
**Database cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.**

Comment: ¿Cuánto espacio libre tienes el servidor donde está el SQL Server?